# Why is this homework question still closed?

Tags: discussion, homework, close-reasons, specific-question

The question *[What mass of water is present as a liquid when equilibrium is established?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/59235/7951)* clearly is a [homework question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3012/7951). The [homework](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag has been added to the question within two minutes after it was posted.

The first attempt of the author may be considered very weak:

> This is in the gases section, so...ideal gas law? I don't know.

After several comments, the author posted a better attempt (at first as an answer, now included in the question):

> (Solution garnered from the comment help. Thanks sir.)
>
> 92.5/760 atm * 5.00 L = n * 0.08206 * 323 K
>
> n = 0.023 mol
>
> Since 1 mol of H20 is 18 g, the answer is .414 g, or B) 0.41 g.

(This solution is already quite reasonable but still contains a mistake.)

*After* the author had posted this attempt, the question attracted five “close” votes and was closed accordingly.

The question was later placed in a reopen review, which it completed with three “leave closed” votes.

That leads me to the questions: Why has this question still to be closed? What else has to be changed about the question in order to make it on topic so that it may be reopened?
(in consideration of our current [homework policy](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/141/7951) and of our new community consensus [Let's not close questions as homework except for blatantly obvious cases (at least for a while)](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3302/7951))

Comment: I voted to close and leave it closed because the post went from a question to a question and answer contained within one post. In hindsight, I would have suggested that the OP answer his/her own question or, alternatively, that one or more of the commentators who provided the answer post it as such.

Comment: I remember my VTC was before the new attempt was added. Anyway, reopening. Personally don't think there's any doubt now

Comment: Also voted to reopen, just in case anyone's keeping score and/or looking at the timeline :)

Answer (score 3):

I reviewed that question yesterday because of a comment flag and noticed there is a reopen flag on it, too. In the then current state I found that the question includes not enough attempt on solving it, but at the same time an answer by the OP including a much better one (although containing an error). In order to make the whole question more helpful for future visitors, I appended the answer to the question and commented:

> I would like to clarify, that this is a homework question according to our policy. Please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. The answer you gave can be considered as the attempt and I will insert it into the question for you. After that I think the question can be reopened.

I did not think I needed to reopen the question manually, since it now contains enough effort according to our policy and I wanted to give the community a chance on a few reopen-reviews.

There are now a total of three reopen-votes on the question, and since there is no evidence that it entered a new reopen review, I will reopen it manually.